# How to make a div to float left/right inside a centered div

Tags: css, html, center

when i want to float a child div to left or right inside the centered parent div, the whole design goes left or right, depending on the float. So, how to float a child div and make the centered parent div in the center.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="child-left"></div>
<div id="child-right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
    padding: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
}
#child-left{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
#child-right{
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Why does parent div go left/right, and doesn't stay in center? And how to make it to stay in center?

Comment: How are you centering the `#parent` div? There is nothing in there that would center `#parent` whether floats were being used or not

Comment: i've put for `margin-right` and `margin-left:auto`

Comment: Inside `#parent`? In that case your code should work ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/PvYbp/)). Maybe you can knock us up an example [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) - or feel free to [edit mine](http://jsfiddle.net/PvYbp/) - that reproduces the problem

Comment: you're right, it was because I didn't set the width for the parent div at first, but left it to be `width:auto`. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [demo](http://jsbin.com/iramom/1/edit)

```
#parent{
    padding: 0px, auto;
    width: 605px;
  height:200px;
  border:solid 1px #f00;
}
#child-left{
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height:200px;
  border:solid 1px #0F0;
}
#child-right{
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
   height:200px;
  border:solid 1px #00F;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused...this won't center the `#parent` element and the example linked in the answer shows that. Why is this the accepted answer? If this solves your problem then I think you need to change your question to avoid confusing any future visitors

Answer (score 3):

For parent div you use this css code

```
margin:0 auto;
width:980px;
```

and for child u use this code for float

```
float:right or left;
width:anypx;
```

best regards

Comment: I do like that too, but in some cases the parent div floats to left/right, although it should stay centered

Comment: you use this style for parent    float:none;

Answer (score 2):

To center the parent element, use `margin: 0 auto;`

```
#parent{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
}
```

There are also lots of spelling mistakes in your code (chile not child), and missing `>` symbols, fix them before you continue

[A working JSFiddle (Click me)](http://jsfiddle.net/7fuUe/)